Filtrado de ruido sobre información obtenida de un trackeo
Estoy trabajando con información obtenida de un trackeo sobre un autito a RC y noté ruido en la información; decidí filtrar con Savgol_Filter() de Scipy y funcionó muy bien, pero los parámetros de window_length y polyorder los obtuve probando.
Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de obtener estos parámetros de manera eficiente o siguiendo alguna teoría.
Muchas gracias!
Agrego fotos y parte del código:
df = pd.read_excel('archivo_excel.xlsx')

df['v_smooth'] = sp.signal.savgol_filter(df.v, 21, 3)

delta_t = df['t'].diff()
delta_V = df['v_smooth'].diff()
acceleration_x = delta_V / delta_t
df_accelerations = pd.DataFrame(
    {'accelerations_x': acceleration_x}
)

df['a_withVSmooth']= (df_accelerations.accelerations_x)

df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

df['a_smoothPlus'] = sp.signal.savgol_filter(df.a_withVSmooth, 21, 2)





t
v
a
x_m
y_rounded
v_smooth
a_withVSmooth
a_smoothPlus




0
0
0
0
7.87371
0.8
-1.27029
0
-20.5514


1
0.0171418
-3.15186
0
7.81971
0.8
-1.78835
-30.2223
-18.0727


2
0.0342835
-2.25133
52.5344
7.78114
0.8
-2.21091
-24.651
-15.7696


3
0.0514253
-3.30195
-61.2901
7.72457
0.8
-2.54732
-19.625
-13.642


4
0.068567
-2.40142
52.5344
7.68343
0.8
-2.80692
-15.1441
-11.6901


5
0.0857088
-3.15186
-43.7786
7.62943
0.8
-2.99905
-11.2084
-9.91369


...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...


85
1.45705
-7.65452
17.5115
0.380571
0.8
-6.59273
27.8448
28.3722


86
1.47419
-5.85345
105.069
0.280286
0.8
-5.96495
36.6228
35.8434


87
1.49133
-4.35257
87.5573
0.205714
0.8
-5.17106
46.3128
43.9794


88
1.50847
-4.20248
8.75573
0.133714
0.8
-4.19545
56.9147
52.7801




Filtrado aplicado color azul -- Sin filtrado color verde


